# Disable Default "Open Windows PowerShell" Right-Click Menu?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-explorer, context-menu

How would one permanently disable <kbd>Shift</kbd> + Right-click → *Open with PowerShell window here* context menu, without simultaneously disabling the PowerShell and elevated PowerShell options in the Explorer File Menu bar?
[image: Screenshot]

The default <kbd>Shift</kbd> + Right-click → *Open with PowerShell window here* context menu can be disabled by adding `LegacyDisable` or `ProgrammaticAccessOnly` strings to registry keys, however, doing so also disables [greys out] the PowerShell and Admin PowerShell options in the Explorer File Menu bar:

```
HKLM\Software\Classes\Directory\shell\PowerShell
HKLM\Software\Classes\DirectoryBackground\shell\PowerShell
HKLM\Software\Classes\Drive\shell\PowerShell
```

- Are these the correct ones to modify; if not, perhaps a CLSID key or a key from `CommandStore`:

  ```
  HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell
  ```

What would be the correct string, dword, or registry modification to disable the <kbd>Shift</kbd> + Right-click context menu without disabling the Explorer File Menu bar options?

Comment: I don't have PowerShell v7.x installed, only v5.1, the one that is included with Windows. I did modify the default "Open with windows powershell here" context menu entry by adding an Icon and changing the MUIVerb to make the menus more consistent. But the guts of the registry key are the same.

Comment: Because the first screenshots were not showing the default Powershell context menu entries from Windows, but the ones I modified. I think the updated screenshots are more concise and succinct.

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas? 

I looked at the PowerShell entries for the Windows Command Store under [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell} registry key. 
For example, "Windows.location.Powershell" and "Windows.location.PowershellAsAdmin" keys have "CommandStateSync", "ExplorerCommandHandler", and "ImpliedSelectionModel" strings/dwords but I am not sure what they do. Can anyone that is really familiar with the registry please chime in? 

Thanks!